# Could there be a bit of reputation leakage between the sites, please?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, stack-exchange, association-bonus

It's a bit frustrating that, even though I'm above rep 100 on Stack Overflow, I'm still restricted with the most basic 'idiot prevention' limits on the other sites as I start there. Really, is it necessary to prevent me from creating a new tag or posting more than once in 20 minutes? I can see holding off edits, or even comments, until I've proved to have a brain in the domain in question.

You could see this as a request for a feature.

Comment: So, are you saying that you want the system to look at your associated accounts and see that if, say, you have a normal amount of rep of one of the Trilogy sites, it will exempt you from part of those limits? Some of them need to be retained, tho. However, if this is what you're saying, I totally agree, as long as it's well-balanced, but I'm not sure if it would be "reputation leakage"...

Comment: Sure, I'm not attached to the 'leakag wording. I'd be pretty content if the inner-post times were the only ones to be exempted, or measured with 'meta-reputation', or whatever terminology appeals.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This already exists: if you have at least 200 reputation on any Stack Exchange site, you can start out with 100 rep on the target site when you associate accounts.

Comment: Thanks for that Jeff, I was just starting up this question again, fortunally I was able to find this before posting it. But I was wondering, I've got 182 reputation at StackOverflow, and I have other associate accounts with low reputation. What if I get 200 reputation on SO now, will I get privilege to the other accounts?

Comment: Forget about that, just found it out, we do get privilege :D And as you told, this gamefication really works!