# Cross Stack privileges

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, stack-exchange, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could there be a bit of reputation leakage between the sites, please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29404/could-there-be-a-bit-of-reputation-leakage-between-the-sites-please)

With the number of sites growing it would be nice if privileges up to a rep level of 50 were awarded across all sites.  If I pop in to Superuser or SharePoint it would be nice to be able to comment everywhere.

The sub-50 permissions seem to be designed to keep new users from abusing privileges before they understand the community.  Once you're established in one community you know the ropes and should be able to contribute to the others without the time-out.

Comment: I notice you don't have many accounts, and not much reputation on any of them. Are you trying to lower the threshold?

Comment: -1 because it already exists and so I'm not sure what more you want

Comment: @simchona, no, I'm fairly new to Stack but had a few occasions where a comment would be appropriate but I could not.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su

Comment: @Jesse Then get trusted somewhere and you'll be able to comment on any SE on which you have an account

Comment: I must have accidentally created separate logins, a legitimate reason why I would not have seen this in action hence the question.  My apologies.

Comment: @simchona, I am, over 500 on overflow.

Comment: @Jesse Your SO account doesn't seem to be linked to the account you're posting with now--the three I can see are MSO, SuperUser, and Database Admins. I suggest you see questions like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120581/account-merge-request) to fix this

Comment: Merged my accounts, all good, thanks for the education all.

Answer (score 10):

This already happens.  From the Meta Stack Overflow [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq):

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than 200 reputation on *any* site in the StackExchange Network, you are awarded a bonus of 100 reputation on all associated accounts. That is, if you have shown that you understand how to behave on one of the SE sites, you are relatively "trusted" on the other ones and are allowed to start commenting everywhere.