# Once a member knows how Stack Exchange works, grant them basic privileges on all sites?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, stack-exchange, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should all linked accounts get the 100 bonus?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5983/should-all-linked-accounts-get-the-100-bonus)
>   [Could there be a bit of reputation leakage between the sites, please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29404/could-there-be-a-bit-of-reputation-leakage-between-the-sites-please)

Now that I know how basic Stack Exchange sites work, why not grant me basic privileges on all sites?

It's like having my hands tied behind my back on each new Stack Exchange site I visit. In fact, this question right here serves two purposes, 1) to find out this answer, and 2) to grant my privileges on Meta Stack Overflow. Only one of these purpose is "true" and the other has an ulterior motive, just the kind of fakeness I would presume you would want to avoid.

And now that I'm thinking about reputation points, I'm worried that this isn't a question that will answer well. Again, not something you really want your "true" visitors to be feeling.

So, now I'll make this into a feature request: Once you grant me the ability to vote and comment on one site, give it to me everywhere. The experienced of you will not share my pain.

Comment: This does happen; you get an automatic 100 reputation bonus to all sites once you pass the 200 barrier on any site in the network.

Comment: You're _almost_ there.  You just need to hit 200 reputation points on a site first.  (This is the community threshold for "knows how StackExchange works")

Comment: @TimStone So users don't have to re-link any more?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50518/157384

Comment: @Farray That's correct, now that the association process is transparent to the user that's all handled automatically as soon as one of the accounts passes the threshold.

Comment: I've got 34k on stack overflow, and I'm not sure I quite know how it all works. :)

Comment: I don't see this a duplicate question. If you are below the 200 rep level then you can not comment and up vote on other sites.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you knew how StackExchange works, you'd also know that this already happens!

[Should all linked accounts get the 100 bonus?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5983/should-all-linked-accounts-get-the-100-bonus)

Comment: Sorry! It most certainly does not happen! EDIT: At least for me.

Comment: @MatthewDoucette - you don't have 200 rep on any one site yet. Once you get there you'll get the bonus.

Comment: @JuanManuel, well this is the answer I was looking for. Please explain this in your answer and I will "accept it"
. I have no idea how a newcomer is supposed to know this 200 barrier of entry. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, I hope my attempt of humor didn't offend you :)