# Share reputation between Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, reputation, stack-exchange, linked-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)
>   [Could there be a bit of reputation leakage between the sites, please?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29404/could-there-be-a-bit-of-reputation-leakage-between-the-sites-please)

I came from Stack Overflow where I participate more frequently, but now I had an issue that I found would be better to be posted on Server Fault, because configuring LDAP isn't a programming topic. It’s my first posting there, which results in enormous restrictions:

- I cannot post my answer
- I had to remove the links

This is caused by the reputation restrictions. They *are* justified for users which are new to the system, but as more and more Stack Exchange sites arise to separate topics, I think if you have once understood the idea of Stack Exchange, you don’t have to be educated on each site again.

So I would like to propose a sharing of the reputation across all Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: You cannot post your answer? And of note: Once you earn 200 rep on one site, an association bonus of 100 rep kicks in for the others, removing most of the basic thresholds.

Comment: This was indeed resolved by implementing the +100 association bonus.

Comment: So you know, it's expected that you research your question before asking it. This has been proposed many, many times in the past.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your Stack Overflow rep is only 80, once you reach 200 rep then you'll start with 100 rep on all other Stack Exchange sites.

This is only to help you over the initial rep restrictions for people who do not understand the Stack Exchange method. I disagree with sharing rep across all Stack Exchange sites: just because you know something about a programming language doesn't mean you know how to configure a server or bake a cake.

Comment: +1, extremely good answer. _just because you know something about a programming language doesn't mean you know how to configure a server or bake a cake._.

Comment: It might be nice to have "friend sites" with partial sharing. For example Stack Overflow, Programmers and Code Review could share reputation at (say) 50%. Game Development at 20% etc depending on how related the sites are

Comment: @RichardTingle to what purpose? Once you're past the initial anti-bot / anti-ignorance 100 rep hurdle it only serves an indication of an individuals commitment to a community (i.e. particular SE site). Creating friend links between several sites would only muddy the waters and create more back-end work. The higher-level privileges like edit reviews require intimate familiarity with the sites rules, and since there are usually subtle differences between sites' rules  you'd get a bunch of not-quite-on-the-money reviewers who earned their wings on another site and another rule-set.

Comment: @ian More for encouragement than anything else, a significant number of people care about reputation (meaningless number or not) and might be more likely to contribute on multiple sites if it carried over a little more. But you do make fair points

Comment: Actually Ian, that's incorrect - you'll start with 101 reputation.

Answer (score 7):

When you reach 200+ points on any of your SE accounts, your *linked* accounts receive a 100 point association bonus, to make this kind of thing easier.

Your highest-scoring account only has 80 points, you need to earn a little more.